# Sitecore DMS stopped recording?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms

Although I see data in the Pages table,

```
Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.DataSets.VisitorDataSet.PagesDataTable pagesDataTable = new VisitorDataSet.PagesDataTable();
```

comes back empty. And I see that the recent recording date is 04/12/2012... considering the fact that the site is being accessed daily... I am trying to understand why dont I see any recording in sitecore_analytics database?
I looked into the config and made sure Analytics is enabled.

Comment: Have you made any code and/or config changes since that date? Is your DMS database at a virtual or physical limit of some sorts? I recommend creating a support ticket with Sitecore (http://support.sitecore.net) since this is a major issue

Comment: I dont recall doing anything that could have made it stop. Unfortunately, my sdn account is blocked and I cannot access the support site. While I am waiting for that to be resolved, I am looking for steps I can take to ensure all the parameters are set right.

Comment: If you're still having issues with Sitecore support, have the license owner for your project call their regional sales manager at Sitecore to expedite the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there was an issue in another piece of code that i call from sitecore pipeline on httpbeginrequest. That code was bombing out and never let other pipeline methods process. Funny thing is it was all hidden and the error never bubbled up to know what was really causing this problem.